# My index finger on bar chord position keeps making poor sounds. Is there a way to improve them?

Tags: chords, classical-guitar

My index finger on bar chord keeps making very poor sounds.

Will there be improvements if I just keep playing or are there ways(like exercises) to improve the sounds?
I have tried to use the side of the finger and place the finger right on the fret, but the sounds are only slightly better.

Comment: Make sure your thumb is completely vertical up the back of the neck, then your fingers should be precisely parallel to the frets. Shouldn't be a problem. Just requires you to open your wrist slightly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trouble with barre](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/115127/trouble-with-barre). There are numerous other similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

The moment I first did this was the moment I finally played a barré:

Don't press with the index finger against the palm. Press with the thumb from the back of the neck against the index finger.

Answer (score 0):

Placed the finger *on* the fret? Should be *behind* the fretwire. And, there really should be no need to squeeze the heck out of the neck.

Yes, turning the index finger so the bony part presses down will help, but consider that it rarely, if ever, needs to press all 6 strings. Other fingers will be slightly closer to the bridge, often covering 3 of those strings.

If you're pressing hard with your thumb, that will maybe work, but it's not the cleverest ploy. In fact, you ought to be able to play a barre chord with no thumb touching the back of the neck. By trapping the guitar body with the right arm, and pulling in with the left hand.

The problem may be an action that just isn't that good. And trying to play barre chords on the 1st few frets isn't the way forward. Get used to barring from 5th fret upwards, until you're happier with the sound.